# Convert SQL query to LINQ with EXISTS and Dates

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

I am new to using LINQ and I'm trying to convert a SQL query to linq within MVC 5.

My query is a follows:

```
SELECT COUNT(Core.CoreName) FROM Core WHERE Core.DCID = @0 
AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM AspNetUsers,Response 
WHERE Core.CoreID = AspNetUsers.CoreID 
AND Response.UserID = AspNetUsers.Id 
AND Core.DCID = @1 
AND YEAR( Response.CreatedOn ) = YEAR( getDate() ) 
AND MONTH( Response.CreatedOn ) = MONTH( getDate() ));
```

Using Linqer I was able to get this but it doesnt seem to work due to the dates:

```
    from Core in
(from Core in db.Core
where
  Core.DCID == @0 &&

    (from Response in db.Response
    where
      Core.CoreID == Response.AspNetUsers.CoreID &&
      Core.DCID == @1 &&
      Response.CreatedOn.Value.Year == Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now).Year &&
      Response.CreatedOn.Value.Month == Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now).Month
    select new {
      Response,
      Response.AspNetUsers
    }).Single() != null
    select new {
      Core.CoreName,
      Dummy = "x"
    })

        group Core by new { Core.Dummy } into g
        select new {
          Column1 = g.Count(p => p.CoreName != null)
        }
```

Can someone please help me fix the linq query or help create a new linq query from the sql. Thanks.

Comment: Remove `Convert.ToDateTime` calls

Comment: Thanks! That worked.